# Comparing textures for matching pixel colours

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am exploring some GLSL and have something I want to try to implement. Here is the situation:

Say I have a texture for what will be displayed on-screen (e.g. 1920x1080), and another (power of 2, e.g. 1024x1024) texture. Every single pixel of both of these textures is 110% guaranteed to be unique in colour (no 2 pixels in one texture are the same colour).

Is it possible to compare the second (1024x1024) texture to the first (1920x1080) texture to determine if any of the pixels of the second have a matching colour to the first?

If this doesn't make any sense, let me know and I will endeavor to re-word it.

Comment: For example: for each fragment being processed in a given render pass, check if that colour exists in a given texture (if that makes sense)

maybe something like:
if(texture1 contains fragmentColor)

Answer (score 0):

What you're attempting to do is a very poor fit for an OpenGL shader. In general, shaders should try to minimize the number of samples they take of each of their textures, and in fact, may be limited in the number they are allowed to use. In order to do what you're suggesting, you would need to sample the comparison image 1024 * 1024 times for every pixel in the input image. That's not going to scale well and it's not the type of work that a GPU is geared towards.

For that task you'd probably be better off doing it on the CPU. You could sort the pixels in the second image first by red, then by green, then by blue. Then for each pixel in the input image do a binary search for that color in the sorted list. You could multithread it for additional speed. But it doesn't seem like a very good fit for a GPU.

Comment: Essentially what I am trying to do is set it up so that when a player can see an NPC on screen, every 'point' that the NPC takes up on the screen that another camera can see, get highlighted ~ every point that the 2 (or more) cameras can see are highlighted in a special way

Comment: If I understand what you're saying, then that's much easier to do than what you proposed. You can shoot a ray from the camera to each polygon of the NPC. If the dot product of the ray and the polygon's normal is negative (meaning the polygon is facing the camera), highlight that polygon.

Comment: random question, is it possible to test if an array of vec3 positions exist within the view space of a camera (can be seen by the camera) in shader?

Comment: @whatsthisnow: yes, you just need the proper view and projection matrices, and can easily test if the point will be inside or outside of the frustum by simply applying the matrices and check if the resulkting clip space coords satisfy the -w <= x,y,z, <= w condition.

Comment: And in fact, you can do that in your vertex shader where you'll be applying the view and projection matrices anyway!

Comment: Thanks for the answers!  I am working on a project for OpenGL in the D language, D seems a fascinating language to me, I am loving it!

Comment: @derhass how exactly would I go about testing if a point is visible in another frustum after it has been transformed into that camera's view space?

Comment: @whatsthisnow: just apply the projection matrix and compare the x,y,z components of the resulting vector against its w component (also check for w > 0, otherwise said condition can never be satisfied)